# Change Text color for Listview in Tabbed Fragment

Tags: java, android, listview, fragment, textcolor

i created a tabbed fragment with viewpager. There is simple listview to show data in farg1. But color of text is coming as white. How to change it to black. listview does not give Textcolor property to set.
below is code used for fragtheme applied to fragment:

```
<style name="FragTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
        <item name="preferenceTheme">@style/PreferenceThemeOverlay.v14.Material</item>
        <!--   <item name="preferenceTheme">@style/PreferenceThemeOverlay</item>-->
    </style>
```

Below is code for layout xml:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tex1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Recently Used Mobile Number List "
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/targetlist" 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

presently set background as black to make it readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can create list_textview.xml and define color in that.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_content"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="sample"
        android:layout_margin="4dip"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

use the same xml in adapter instead of using `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1`

```
arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(getActivity(),R.layout.list_textview, R.id.list_content,recentlistarray); 
recentlist.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

OR

```
ArrayAdapter adapter=new ArrayAdapter(
            this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listItems){

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View view =super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

            TextView textView=(TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
            textView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

            return view;
        }
    };
    recentlist.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

Comment: u mean custom listview to be used.

Comment: not really it is not custom listview we are just changing the layout file for which text is added. you will not have any other direct attribute to set color  for text.

Comment: There is one way you can get textview used in listview in adapter class and set color for that.

Comment: arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, recentlistarray);
        recentlist.setAdapter(arrayAdapter); this is how i set. i m not getting setListAdapter method.

Comment: listview.setadapter(arratAdapter);

Comment: Replace android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 by R.layout.list_textView.

Comment: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView

Comment: you can use any of the approach.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134890/discussion-between-panache-and-santosh-kumar).